# Correctly initializing and retrieving preferences in a Xtext-based Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences, xtext

I am writing an Eclipse plugin using Xtext 2. I have provided my own preferences by writing my own `RootPreferencePage` class:

```java
package org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui.editor.preferences;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.preferences.LanguageRootPreferencePage;
public class GFLanguageRootPreferencePage extends LanguageRootPreferencePage {
    @Override
    protected void createFieldEditors() {
        addField(new StringFieldEditor("PREF", "&Label:", getFieldEditorParent()));
    }
    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        getPreferenceStore().setDefault("PREF", "default-value");
    }
}
```

and binding it in the UI module as usual:

```java
public Class<? extends org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.preferences.LanguageRootPreferencePage> bindLanguageRootPreferencePage() {
    return org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui.editor.preferences.GFLanguageRootPreferencePage.class;
}
```

This works fine; I can save a preference, close and reopen Eclipse, go to the preferences window again and see the value that I saved.
However the problem is when I try to retrieve the preference values programmatically. I use the following bit of code:

```java
IPreferencesService prefs = Platform.getPreferencesService();
String s = prefs.getString(QUALIFIER, "PREV", "fallback", null);
```

This works fine when staying within the same instance of Eclipse, but after restarting Eclipse my attempt to retrieve the preference programmatically fails. The funny thing is I know my preferences are correctly saved by checking in the preference window.

I guess this is an issue with the *preference scope* as described [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html) and [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in my programmatic retrieval of preference values.

**UPDATE**

I have since noticed that when I remove the call to `setDefault(...)` from within the `init()` method, things work entirely correctly. That is, I can set preferences via the UI, reload Eclipse, and retrieve those values programmatically without a problem.

So the issue has now become that I need to find the correct place for my call to `setDefault(...)`. Based on [this same article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html), I have extended the `` extension point as follows:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences">
    <initializer
        class="org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui.editor.preferences.GFPreferenceInitializer">
    </initializer>
</extension>
```

and with the implementing class:

```java
package org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui.editor.preferences; 
public class GFPreferenceInitializer extends AbstractPreferenceInitializer {
    @Override
    public void initializeDefaultPreferences() {
        IPreferenceStore store = GFActivator.getInstance().getPreferenceStore();
        store.setDefault("PREV", "default-value");
    }
}
```

This code is being executed, but for some reason when I open my preferences window and click "Restore defaults", the fields are simply blanked.. the defaults I am trying to set/initialize do not seem to make their way to the preferences window, so I am stuck yet again!

Comment: What are you using as your QUALIFIER and your KEY?  See `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.preferences.PreferenceStoreAccessImpl.getWritablePreferenceStore()` for where XText creates the preference store.

Comment: In my case the QUALIFIER is `"org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.GF"`, which I got directly from my `plugin.xml` file. In this example, KEY would be `"PREF"`.

Comment: I've found that when I comment out `getPreferenceStore().setDefault(..);` in the `init()` method, then things seem to work properly.. so maybe this setting of the default values is simply in the wrong place?

Comment: the vogella link is now: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think I have solved my own problem.
I needed to specify the preference store in the `init()` method as follows:

```java
package org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui.editor.preferences;
public class GFLanguageRootPreferencePage extends LanguageRootPreferencePage {
    ...
    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setPreferenceStore(GFActivator.getInstance().getPreferenceStore());
    }
}
```

I really should have read the articles I linked to more carefully!

Comment: Additionally, I also needed to start using `org.grammaticalframework.eclipse.ui` as the **qualifier**.